# Issue with returning value in recursive function PHP

Tags: php, recursion, return

Have some issue with returning a value in recursive function. But I can echo it.
What could be wrong with this?

```
function calculate($i,$count=1)
{
    $str_i = (string)$i;
    $rslt = 1;

    for ($k=0; $k<strlen($str_i); $k++) {
        $rslt = $str_i[$k]*$rslt;
    }

    if ( strlen((string)$rslt) > 1 ) {
        $this->calculate($rslt,++$count);
    } elseif ( strlen((string)$rslt) == 1 ) {
        return $count;  
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of this function? Can you please provide a test input? If `strlen((string)$rslt) == 0` the return is never reached.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This function calculate the Gardner's number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` in you code the value returned in the recursive call is not used. You don't set it to a value or `return` it. Thus every call except the base case doesn't return a value.

Try this:

```
function calculate($i,$count=1)
{
    $str_i = (string)$i;
    $rslt = 1;

    for ($k=0; $k<strlen($str_i); $k++) {
        $rslt = $str_i[$k]*$rslt;
    }

    if ( strlen((string)$rslt) > 1 ) {
        return $this->calculate($rslt,$count+1); // I changed this line
    } elseif ( strlen((string)$rslt) == 1 ) {
        return $count;  
    }
}
```

Now we return the value returned by the recursive call. Note I changed `++$count` to `$count+1` since it's bad style to mutate when using recursion.

Comment: Yea, it works! Thanks man, you rock!! Sorry, can't vote your answer up because of my low rating( Thank you one more time!!